# Is it grammatically correct to add 요 to everything?

Tags: spoken-korean, polite, polite-speech

I thought 요 was only a verb ending, and my textbook did not introduce adding it to all sorts of parts of speech, which I hear regularly in Korea. From the well-known 저도요 to 이렇게요, noun + 요 etc. Is that actually grammatically correct?

Comment: I think you can add '요' to make honorific form in case you don't know what to add. But basically, there are some exceptions not to use 요.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't add it to everything.  For example you can't add it certain (for lack of a better word) 'standard' endings such as (스)ㅂ니다, (십)시오, (으)ㅂ시다, (어/아/여)라, (는)구나, 게, (이)오, and a few things like that.

But you can add it to a lot of things.

By the way, when you add it to a noun, you should use 이요 after a consonsant ending.

Comment: Which things exactly? And I heard 이렇게요 for sure

Comment: 요 can be added after ㅂ니다, that's a funny honorific expression used by native speakers.

Comment: -ㅂ니다요 is possible but would sound very archaic (and/or funny).  I think I've only heard them in historical dramas (사극).

Comment: 이렇게 is not the 게 i'm talking about...이렇게 is an adverb that means "like this" or "in this way" ...the 게 i'm talking about is an imperative (command) ending that is a little old fashioned but still used among men in some settings.  Beyond the list I gave and few other endings that are kind of old-fashioned, I think you can add 요 or 이요 to anything.